# Arduino Uno Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino-uno

What is the best way to be able to type in a statement like "Select Process 1" in the serial monitor and have it respond with predefined statements such as "The heat is on"?  I have tried parseInt and strings, but cannot get it to do what I want.  Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://processing.org/) software. It is called Processing. You can send commands from your PC or mobile phone. And you program Arduino to do what in which statement.